# Webpack 2 runtime replacement for RequireJS config paths?

Tags: webpack-2

In `RequireJS` one could add resolve paths by calling

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'abc': 'for/anything/starting/with/abc/webpack/should/go/look/here'
  }
});
```

Webpack 2 supports AMD format, how can I do something similar there?

When looking through the documentation almost everything seems to happen during build time with Webpack and I only know these extra paths in runtime after reading my domain configuration with an ajax call.

Comment: Even though Webpack supports AMD format it is still a static bundler, not a module loader. So it doesn't look like my scenario can be realized with Webpack. https://twitter.com/TheLarkInn/status/789968589419745280

Answer (score 0):

Even though Webpack supports AMD format it is still a static bundler, not a module loader. So my scenario can't be realized with Webpack.
https://twitter.com/TheLarkInn/status/789968589419745280

Edit:
My scenario is that I want to be able to load AMDs in runtime that are not known to me at build time.

Webpack offers externals, to host for example jQuery in a CDN instead of bundling. But you specify that in build config, hence must be known at build time.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

It also offers bundle splitting, but the bundles are built together at build time.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Comment: Hi! I think you should put this information as a update for your question. This way, people will know that you already has that information and hence can provide with alternative ways to overcome the issue.

Comment: I believe it is the answer and it is always possible to add another answer.
I've added it as comment also now. You believe I should delete the answer?

Comment: If you think it is truly the final answer, you should provide more details so others can figure out if their scenario is equal to yours.